# Retract push notification on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

I haven't come across a documented method of doing it, but is it at all possible to retract expired notifications/alerts pushed to an iPhone?

I know it can be done in theory, as the prime example is iMessage: if you receive an iMessage but read it on another device, the unread message notification on the lock screen will disappear from any other devices subscribed to the iMessage account in question.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe with continuity (handoff) in iOS 8? You can update ongoing activities between devices. (A shot in the dark, I know)

Comment: Outlook.app does it for mail notifications *sometimes*, I haven't figured out under what circumstances, though.